# Golang invopop jsonschema usage of if/then/else

Tags: go, jsonschema

I'm using the [library invopop/jsonschema](https://github.com/invopop/jsonschema) for generating our json-schema based on go struct tags. But I struggle on how to use the if/then/else attributes.

I was doing something like this

```golang
type Boulou struct {
    Name              string                   `json:"name" jsonschema:"required,minLength=1,description=unique name"`
    Transformers      []TransformerConfig `json:"transformers" jsonschema:"title=transformers,if=properties.kind.const=convert_swim,then=required[0]=convert_swim_config"`
}
```

But does not seems to work (i made a [go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/28TwUfjR7l-) if you would like to play with).

Thanks in advance !

Resources:

- json-schema spec for conditions: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These complex use-cases aren't supported all that well using Go tags in invopop/jsonschema. Anything that breaks out of regular use-cases I'd recommend implementing the `JSONSchema()` method so you can define the object manually. Following your example:

```
type Boulou struct {
    Name              string              `json:"name"`
    Transformers      []TransformerConfig `json:"transformers"`
}

func (Boulou) JSONSchema() *jsonschema.Schema {
  props = orderedmap.New()
  props.Set("name", &jsonschema.Schema{
    Type: "string",
    Title: "Name",
  })
  props.Set("transformers", &jsonschema.Schema{
    Type: "array",
    Title: "Transformers",
    Items: &jsonschema.Schema{
      Ref:  ".....",
      If:   "properties.kind.const=convert_swim",
      Then: "required[0]=convert_swim_config",
    },
  })
  return &jsonschema.Schema{
    Type:       "object",
    Title:      "Boulou",
    Properties: props,
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this directly, but I'm sure you get the idea. You'll need to figure out what the `Ref` for your `TransformerConfig` is manually.

Update: there is now a new [PR #52](https://github.com/invopop/jsonschema/pull/52) which once launched, should make this much easier to do!

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yeah, i got the idea :)
I'll do it, but this will stop the library from generating the properties based on the struct tags. It's a shame but at least I can validate correctly my json !

Comment: Updated, but commenting also, a new PR is on the way which should make this much easier: https://github.com/invopop/jsonschema/pull/52